# merge синхронизация двух таблиц mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-merge

помогите запутался , есть две таблицы Models и cars_v , поле model в таблице Models имеет ограничение unique , необходимо вставить записи из второй таблицы отсутствующие в первой , ругается на уникальность , в чем ошибка ?

```
MERGE INTO Models
using cars_v
ON Models.model=cars_v.model
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN       INSERT (model)VALUES(cars_v.model);
```

Спасибо.

Comment: _"поле model в таблице Models имеет ограничение unique"_ а в `cars_v` поле `model` уникально? Если нет, то это может быть причиной ошибки.

Comment: вместо using cars_v попробовать using (select distinct model from cars_v)

Comment: KadafiVSC , спасибо , помогло